# Does phpMyAdmin pose security risk on production

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

The VPS I was using used to have phpMyAdmin pre-installation option but removed it stating it poses security risk. Does it?

If so do you recommend an alternative for browsing DB on production (other than running SQL commands in console)?

Comment: I'd recommend running SQL commands in console. It's way more reliable than clicking thousands buttons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any extra software you add to a system adds complexity. Complexity is the enemy of security.

PHP webapps are notorious for sloppy coding and certainly phpMyAdmin has had [more than its share of security holes](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/security/) in the past. You can certainly mitigate the damage by eg. putting behind HTTPS with a client certificate, but that's not going to prevent cross-site-request-forgery attacks.

For a production machine, I'd really prefer to stick to the console.

Answer (score 7):

It depends. If you can get all the access to PhpMyAdmin through SSL only, and enforce strong password security on the web site, it can be secure.

Otherwise it's opening your entire DB server to the world in clean view.

Answer (score 5):

1)install classic PHPMyAdmin
2)add ssl to your phpmyadmin
3)add .htacess and protect it with a password

Comment: also you can add IP filtering for access specific directories of your domain.

Answer (score 2):

More third party software - more issues you can get. My recommendation is to use mysql console on vps and denied outside connections to mysql with root rights

Answer (score 2):

I recommend setting up phpMyAdmin on your local box. Then set up a ssh tunnel to your production box and forward mysql's port to your local machine. Configure your local phpMyAdmin to connect to that forwarded port.

That is, if you really want to use phpMyAdmin.

Comment: In that case, you can use MySQL Workbench too. Better even.

Answer (score 1):

There have definitely been security wholes in the past. Probably will find new ones in the future. It's always a risk to open that kind of a tool to public web space.

I recommend installing database management software, and connecting to your production DB through an SSH tunnel. If you're on a Mac, I'd install Sequel Pro for free. On other platforms Navicat (and other similar software) is available, but it does cost money.