# Unknown query: call update_oai()

Tags: php, mysql, pear

I am working on an old project and just saw a function:

```
$query = 'call update_oai()';
$res = $_DB->queryRaw($query);
```

I really can't find what is this query: "call update_oai". Any idea?

Comment: `update_oai` is the name of the `STORED PROCEDURE`.

Comment: you can get at the contents of the stored procedure by `SHOW PROCEDURE CODE update_oai;`

Comment: You can view a list of all procedures with `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS`.

Comment: @Orangepill the SHOW PROCEDURE CODE is disabled in my MySQL

Comment: @EdGibbs, tahnk you very much.

Comment: also if you want a list of the stored procedures on the database you can use `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a stored procedure, have a look in the stored procedures created for your database.

Comment: Thank you, how to find the stored procedures?

Comment: It all depends on the user interface you are using, for phpmyadmin have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115573/how-do-i-view-my-stored-procedures-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3):

CALL statement invokes a stored procedure, in your case the stored procedure with name `update_oai`.

Syntax:

> CALL sp_name([parameter[,...]])

See documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, the `CALL` is used to call the store procedures and the name of procedure is `update_oai` here that have no arguments.

So there is calling a store procedure.

Answer (score 1):

This is a store procedure in mysql, you can find procedure in phpmyadmin.